# Using Sass sourcemaps with multiple files included

Tags: sass

I'm moving my workflow to use sourcemaps with Sass, and it was going well, but I'm having trouble with it overwriting my `main.scss` every time I make a change in Chrome Devtools.

My file structure is like this:

```
scss - main.scss
  |- inc
      |-_mixins.scss
      |-_typo.scss
      |- etc...
```

and `main.scss` contains multiple `@import "inc/mixins";` lines, obviously each with different filenames.

I created a sourcemap, using `sass --sourcemap scss/main.scss css/main.css` and then started watching the files using `sass --sourcemap --watch scss:css`, (all found [in this tut](https://medium.com/what-i-learned-building/getting-started-with-css-sourcemaps-and-in-browser-sass-editing-b4daab987fb0)).

I've also mapped working files in Chrome Devtools.

It works initially, in that if I examine the elements in DevTools, I see the code in SCSS.  If I edit a value, it overwrites my `scss/main.scss` with the contents of `css/main.css`, which is massively weird.

Anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out.

I followed the tut to get this working, but had mapped the local files incorrectly.

If you are manually setting up SASS sourcemapping, you must be careful to map included files to the correct locations.  Somehow I had one mapped to main.scss, and so it was overwriting it on changes.